# What ssd connector is this?

Tags: ssd, connector

I've got a ssd that has this type of connector:

[image]

It has 26 flat pins. I've been unsuccessfully looking all over to have a clue on what kind connector it could be. Not sure if it's a usual drive connector as SAS or Sata...

Its size is a between 1 and 2 inches.

Comment: Where did you find this connector? Can you give us more context? 2.5" SSD? Laptop? etc...

Comment: Don't mSata connectors have two parts with a gap inbetween?

It's inside a camera memory card, but the reader broke, and i'd like to find a way to mount it on my computer

Comment: Doesn't look to me like an SSD.

Comment: Well the ssd is inside the card box. It must be some kind of adapter in between. But I don't want to take the risk to open it and destroy the memory card...

Comment: It may be an adapter that needs to be pulled off.

Comment: yeah I think so.. What would be great would be to have the name of this side of the adapter :)

Comment: Interesting mystery. What is the make and model of the SSD? Do you have any details of the reader? I wonder if its some kind if nonstandard interface rooted in floppy disk technology (Google tells me floppy disk/connectors had 26 pins - although they certainly didn't look like that!)

Comment: I don't have the exact make and model of the SSD.The memory card is from a small company that built the video camera in 2010's. It must have at least 200Mbs speddrate. They went in bankruptcy years ago... That's the reason why I tried to have a clue before trying to open the card itself. My guess is they put a generic ssd behind the adaptor to make it proprietary. First part was to find the type of the connector (thought it would be easier), as I guess there is also some software work to make the card proprietary...